# How to tell what user "Integrated Security" is running as?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Running on my dev machine, connected to the db on another machine with this connection string in Visual Studio:

```
Data Source=dev-db,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
```

I'm connected, life is good. Trying to run the EF Core command
`Update-Database` I get this error:

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDb'

The question: what user is attempting to create the table and how do I figure that out? I know how to grant access on the db side, but knowing what user needs access is the mystery. I saw an answer here about a logon trigger, but that answer didn't seem to be a useful answer as it had no upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integrated Security=True` means to connect to SQL Server using Windows Integrated Auth using the identity of the user executing the program.  So it's you.